# Business WiFi/Guest WiFi/Zyxel Firewall Set up

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall

Im looking for some direction. We have a small business network set up that I am tasked with cleaning up. However, I really do not have the expertise.

The main challenge I am trying to solve now is setting up the guest WiFi so it's on a different subnet (I assume this is the right term). So if guests are using the Guest WiFi, they are isolated from the main network of computers.

Our internet is provided through a Cable Modem, which then goes through a router (Both supplied by our ISP). The WiFi on that router is turned off. The router is connected to the WAN of our Zyxel Firewall.

We have an Asus Wireless router that is connected to one of the LANs of the Firewall. The Wireless router is already set up with our internal SSID and a Guest SSID, both with different passwords.

But as I see it, since it's just one router, and connected to the LAN, there is no way to isolate them, right? (Also, I can not access the WiFi router admin page remotely, through wifi or wired (we also have a gigabit switch that is connected to one of the LAN ports on the firewall). I assume there may be a firewall setting that would allow me to get to it. Otherwise, I have to get into the network closet and plug in directly I suppose - But I would like to fix that).

I am thinking I need to either turn on the ISP router's WiFi and set it up as Guest. Or get another WiFi Router plugged into another LAN, set up as Guest, and configure it independently.

Again, most of the settings and connections are a mystery to me. But I can use Google as needed. :)

Asus RT-AC1200
Zyxel USG 110

Comment: How large is the network? When you connect to the Asus, do you get the same IP address as if connected directly to the ZyXEL? Does the ZyXEL firewall have only one LAN configured or multiple?

Comment: I will connect to the Asus a little later and check that out.
The Zyxel has 2 wan, 1 opt, 4 lan/dmz ports. 1 Wan and the OPT are the only ones not being used.
1 Lan is for the WiFi, 1 for a network drive, 1 for Security cams, and 1 to connect the gigiabit switch.

Comment: We have a 10-person crew. though its seldom that we are all in the office at the same time. A couple of printers. Mostly laptops per person, but a couple of desktops workstations used as needed. A VOIP phone system.

Comment: I mean, are all of the LAN ports assigned to the same single subnet?

Comment: Yes, same subnet